# TextField not being added to ScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextfield

When I input the following code, the textfields I added are not being displayed in the scrollview:

.h

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *firstField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *secondField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *thirdField;
```

.m (viewDidLoad)

```
self.firstField.placeholder = @"First";
self.firstField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.firstField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue Light" size:50.0];

self.secondField.placeholder = @"Second";
self.secondField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.secondField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue Light" size:50.0];

self.thirdField.placeholder = @"Third";
self.thirdField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.thirdField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue Light" size:50.0];

[self.scrollView addSubview:self.firstField];
[self.firstField autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdgesWithInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero excludingEdge:ALEdgeRight];
[self.firstField autoMatchDimension:ALDimensionWidth toDimension:ALDimensionWidth ofView:self.scrollView];
[self.firstField autoMatchDimension:ALDimensionHeight toDimension:ALDimensionHeight ofView:self.scrollView];

[self.scrollView addSubview:self.secondField];
[self.secondField autoPinEdge:ALEdgeLeft toEdge:ALEdgeRight ofView:self.firstField];
[self.secondField autoMatchDimension:ALDimensionWidth toDimension:ALDimensionWidth ofView:self.scrollView];
[self.secondField autoMatchDimension:ALDimensionHeight toDimension:ALDimensionHeight ofView:self.scrollView];

[self.scrollView addSubview:self.thirdField];
[self.thirdField autoPinEdge:ALEdgeLeft toEdge:ALEdgeRight ofView:self.secondField];
[self.thirdField autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdgesWithInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero excludingEdge:ALEdgeLeft];
[self.thirdField autoMatchDimension:ALDimensionWidth toDimension:ALDimensionWidth ofView:self.scrollView];
[self.thirdField autoMatchDimension:ALDimensionHeight toDimension:ALDimensionHeight ofView:self.scrollView];

self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

I have self.scrollView is within a scrollView by the way (in a pageviewcontroller). I am using PureLayout to position the text fields, and I'm pretty sure the way I did it is correct. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

yes you are missing some code,if you wan't to add UITextField programmatically you must to set size and position on you're view, something like that:

```
self.firstField.frame = CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 40);
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I put that code in after `[self.scrollView addSubview:self.firstField]` and it still doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

AutoLayout work slightly differently with UIScrollView:  It relate to its `contentView` instead of its frame.  [This is explained here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html).

You will need to set your UIScrollView's `contentView` property since its CGSizeZero by default.  Then if you want your 3 UITextfields to appear side by side, you'll have to change their width constraint because otherwise they will fill the whole contentSize.